# Conversion of sequence of PNGs to movie using ffmpeg on Fedora 18

Tags: images, fedora, ffmpeg

I have a series of PNG images called Temp01.png, Temp02.png, ..., Temp99.png which I am attempting to convert into a movie using ffmpeg. I am using the command:

```
ffmpeg -i Temp%02d.png -f avi -vcodec huffyuv output.avi
```

... but to no avail. The command works perfectly on Mac OS X 10.5 and Ubuntu 12.10, but not on Fedora 187.

When run on Fedora, ffmpeg generates a movie file of approximately the right size, but only shows the first frame for the whole movie, i.e. the image Temp01.png is shown for the entirely length of the movie. Controlling the input and/or output frame rate using `-r` seems to do nothing other than modify the length of movie. No error messages are generated.

I have reinstalled ffmpeg and all the relevant gstreamer packages from the repositories. I would be grateful if someone could help me diagnose the problem, or point me in the right direction.

The output from FFmpeg is as follows:

```
ffmpeg version 1.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec  4 2012 08:14:17 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC) 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
  libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
  libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
  libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
  libavfilter     3. 17.100 /  3. 17.100
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from 'Temp%02d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:03.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 947x946, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[huffyuv @ 0xfa6f20] using huffyuv 2.2.0 or newer interlacing flag
Output #0, avi, to 'output.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf54.29.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: huffyuv (HFYU / 0x55594648), rgb24, 947x946, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> huffyuv)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   17 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=   28257kB time=00:00:00.68 bitrate=340418.8kbitsframe=   30 fps= 28 q=0.0 size=   49862kB time=00:00:01.20 bitrate=340389.5kbitsframe=   41 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=   68142kB time=00:00:01.64 bitrate=340379.2kbitsframe=   54 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=   89747kB time=00:00:02.16 bitrate=340372.5kbitsframe=   67 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=  111351kB time=00:00:02.68 bitrate=340368.4kbitsframe=   78 fps= 25 q=0.0 size=  129632kB time=00:00:03.12 bitrate=340365.9kbitsframe=   87 fps= 24 q=0.0 size=  144588kB time=00:00:03.48 bitrate=340364.4kbitsframe=   91 fps= 24 q=0.0 Lsize=  151237kB time=00:00:03.64 bitrate=340367.1kbits/s    
video:151230kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.005079%
```

The following is the output of a static build of ffmpeg, run on Mac OS X 10.5. In this case, the movie is generated as expected.

```
ffmpeg version 1.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  7 2013 11:12:33 with gcc 4.0.1 (GCC) (Apple Inc. build 5493)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --arch=x86 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
  libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
  libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
  libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, image2, from 'Temp%02d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:03.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 1440x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[huffyuv @ 0x1809e20] using huffyuv 2.2.0 or newer interlacing flag
Output #0, avi, to 'output.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf54.59.106
    Stream #0:0: Video: huffyuv (HFYU / 0x55594648), rgb24, 1440x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> huffyuv)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   91 fps= 15 q=0.0 Lsize=  216506kB time=00:00:03.64 bitrate=487257.2kbits/s    
video:216498kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.003548%
```

Comment: Please show the full, uncut FFmpeg output. What version of FFmpeg, specifically, did you use? Have you checked with a [recent static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html)?

Comment: I'm using version 1.0.1 from the repos, built on Dec 4 2012. I have also tried the latest static build. I have added the full output from version 1.0.1 to the original post

Comment: Also showing the ffmpeg output of a working version may provide some useful information.

Comment: I've added the FFmpeg output from a working version to the original post.